# rendering simple input element inside mvc razor view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's say that I have following html which works for my form

```
<input 
      data-msg-date="The field RequiredDateDemo must be a date." 
      data-msg-required="The RequiredDateDemo field is required." 
      data-rule-date="true" 
      data-rule-required="true" 
      id="RequiredDateDemo" name="RequiredDateDemo" type="text" value="" />
```

If I have model like

```
public class MyModel{
     [Required]
     public DateTime RequiredDateDemo { get; set; }
}
```

> how can I generate that above html code using html helpers inside mvc
>   razor view?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace CustomHelpers
{
  public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value)
    {
      var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
      builder.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
      builder.MergeAttribute("name", name);
      builder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
  }
}
```

http://dotnet-helpers.com/2013/08/05/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-using-mvc-4-razor/

Answer (score 1):

If you want do it only from .cshtml page then you can do it by following way:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequiredDateDemo, new { data_msg_date="The field RequiredDateDemo must be a date.", data_msg_required="The RequiredDateDemo field is required.",data_rule_date="true",data_rule_required="true"   })
```